# Why does this AnimatedSwitcher not animate the change?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to animate text to switch between two values

```
AnimatedSwitcher(
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      (_smallTitle == true) ? Text('Text1/', style:TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0)) : Container(),
                      Text(
                        (_smallTitle == false) ? _largeHeaderText : _smallHeaderText,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

This code does successfully switch the text when I trigger a change in my '_smallTitle` bool value.  But the change is not animated at all

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think you forgot to call `setState` in your code, where do you set `_smallTitle` value?

Comment: @Hamed I set it elsewhere and use setstate.  The value properly changes.  It just doesn't animate is the issue...

Comment: please add `_smallTitle` set value code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main work for `AnimatedSwitcher` is to animate between child. But in this case we are having single and same widget (`column`) as child. That's why we can't see animation. We need to pass a child based on condition. Like

```dart
AnimatedSwitcher(
            duration: Duration(seconds: 4),
            child: _smallTitle
                ? Column(
                    key: ValueKey("child1"), // provide key
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Text1/',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        _smallHeaderText,
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                : Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(_largeHeaderText),
                    ],
                  )),
```

**But we can trick something with `key`.**

```dart
AnimatedSwitcher(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
          child: Column(
            key: ValueKey(_smallTitle ? "small child Key" : "largeChild key"),
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              (_smallTitle == true)
                  ? Text('Text1/', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                  : Container(),
              Text(
                (_smallTitle == false) ? _largeHeaderText : _smallHeaderText,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

> use separate `key`  for child.